# Using fscanf to scan for + or - type symbols

Tags: c, scanf

what do I test for in `fscanf` if I'm checking for a `'+'` or `'-'` or `'%'` etc.

for example, if I was testing for an int I would do:

```
    if(fscanf(read,"%d", &d)) //do something
    else if (fscanf(read,"%s", s)) // do something else
    else if fscanf(read,"%?", ?) //case for + - % /
```

relevant code:

```
while(feof(read) == 0){


    //printf("help me");
    if(fscanf(read,"%d", &d)) {
        /* this makes sure that ints preceding "pick" etc are not
         * counted as ints that are pushed onto the stack. Further this makes sure
         * the testing for this does not "eat" and of the words in the file
         */ 

        //if (d == '+') {
            //fprintf (write, "\t+ DETECTED\n");
        //}
        const long pos = ftell(read); // stores current position
        //checks if the next thing 
        if (fscanf(read,"%s", s)){
            if ((strcmp(s , "pick") == 0 || (strcmp(s , "eq") == 0))){
                //fprintf (write, "%d %s called\n", d, s);
            }
            else {
                push(d, write);
                //undo the word we "ate" 
                fseek(read, pos, SEEK_SET);
            }
        } else push(d, write);
    } 

    else if (fscanf(read,"%s", s)){ 
        if (strcmp(s , "defun") == 0) {
            fscanf(read,"%s", s);
            printdefun (s, write);
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "return") == 0) {
            printreturn (write);
        }
        else if (strcmp(s , "return") == 0) {
            fprintf (write, "\t+ detected\n");
        }
    }
    else if (fscanf(read,"%c", &c)){ 
        if (c == '+') {
            fprintf (write, "\t+ DETECTED\n");
        }
    }
```

text file:

```
    defun main
15 10 +
return
```

Note that the "+ detected" never gets printed

Comment: firstly should check the return codes of `feof` and `fscanf` properly. `feof` returns non-zero [not necessarily 1], but you need `fscanf` to return 1 for you to match exactly one element. also post the entirety of the code [for a small program]

Comment: feof is scanning the whole file when I check != 1..?
I'm using fscanf to tell if thing scanned was int or string...
Program is 500+ lines :(

Comment: `feof` could return a nonzero value [let say 3] when it hits the EOF, and your check `!= 1` would still evaluate as true..

Comment: ok, why are you looking for an integer here: `if(fscanf(read,"%d", &d)) {` - we should first look for the two keywords `defun` and `main`

Comment: there are unlimited keywords. just have only put in cases for defun and main

Comment: so what is the syntax describing the file (the other keywords and the bnf)

Comment: Wait I think I see the problem. I think the problem is that it is reading the + as a positive number. Any way around this?

Comment: well you could `fseek` backwards or `ungetc` and then read it again as a char format

Comment: would recommend splitting the fiddly `fscanf` and `fseek` into semantically well-named functions. also probly should start a new SO as we're off topic now